authentication without using emails as userid? Supabase example?
In Dexie-Cloud userId stores emails as ids. This expose user data I would prefer not to.
I presume it is impossible extend the default dexie-cloud authentication to store the email eleswhere and use UUID or similar value, right?
Instead I'm thinking of using Supabase for the auth. Is there an example of using Supabase with Dexie-Cloud? Bonus, if there is sveltekit example?

It's true that dexie-cloud defaults to using email address as user-id. However, authentication can be replaced with any other alternative.
Try using something like auth0 to do the authentication (https://github.com/auth0/node-auth0) or any of the alternatives at https://www.opensourcealternative.to/alternativesto/auth0
Then integrate dexie cloud with it using the sample at
https://dexie.org/cloud/docs/db.cloud.configure()#example-integrate-custom-authentication . The only way various authentication solutions may vary is how to retrieve userId (and optionally more claims) within the server-side endpoint. The example assumes it's in req.user but that may vary.
If you could find some very clean standalone example where supabase is only used for authentication, so that an app knows the username server side, you can use that and add the new endpoint for providing dexie-cloud tokens.

I'm trying with Supabase & SvelteKit. I have the login working properly. However, when I hook it up to Dexie, then the /dexie-cloud-tokens never get invoked (i.e. posted to). Is there additional things that need doing in SvelteKit?

you need to create an API route such as server.js file under src/routes/dexie-cloud-tokens that has the similar code as the express example shows. Exactly how that is done in sveltekit should be possible to find out from sveltekit docs but it should make it's own rest call to dexie-cloud just like the express sample and return the exact json it gets from there.
